# iPhone video screen capture not on simulator and do not jailbreak

Tags: iphone, video, capture

I am looking for a software that can capture my iPhone screen without jailbreak and not on simulator (because I don't have source code).

I have google it and cannot find the perfect solutions; is it not possible on iPhone without jailbreak?

Your comment is highly appreciated.

Tony

Comment: Do you want to take the screen shot in device?

Comment: No, I know I can press the HOME + Power button to take a screen shot but I am looking for a video capture instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can not video capture from an iDevice with out being jail broken, because in order to capture video you need to be able to break out of Apple's sandbox.  Jailbreaking really isn't that difficult, and it opens you up to a wide range of tweaks and other software.  If you were going to jailbreak your iPhone I would recommend "Display Recorder" as the best screen capture option, and it's only $5 in the cydia store.

Comment: Thanks, since, I still cannot find a solution to do video recording without jailbreak. I know that is easy, the reason can't jailbreak due to the device is not me but provided from client. Finally, I need to ask for the apps from client and install it into my iPhone and jailbreak it to capture. Finally, I did it but still no a way to capture video without jailbreak.